# How to open file by it's name in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have thousands of files and foldesr and cant browse them in `File` | `Open` or `Explorer` windows because it is very slow.

Can I open file by it's filename in VS Code?

---

If I press `Ctrl-P` and enter my filepath, relative to opened directory

```
mydir1/mydir2/myfile-a:b.cfg
```

it says `No results found`.

Comment: If the file exists in your open subdirectory, Cmd+P in mac would work.

Comment: it exists, but nested

Comment: I have never seen `:` in filenames ... Does ist work with a file like `myfile.cfg`?

Answer (score 1):

You can open your folder in code, then use Ctrl+P (or Cmd+P on mac) and type in the file's name ([documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks#_quick-open)).

Alternatively, if you don't mind using the command line, you can type in your terminal:

```
code myfile.txt myfile2.html
```

(i.e. `code` followed by a list of files to open), and the specified files will open in VS code.

Comment: Note that you can also open vscode in the current directory with `code .`

Comment: How to specify filename in `Ctrl-P` window? In quotes? As relative path? How to escape symbols? It doesn work for `mydir1/mydir2/myfile-a:b.cfg`